# Exporting plain text header and image to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am fairly new to Python, but I'm getting stuck trying to pass an image file into a header during the `DataFrame.to_excel()` portion of my file.

Basically what I want is a picture in the first cell of the Excel table, followed by a couple of rows (5 to be exact) of text which will include a date (probably from `datetime.date.today().ctime()` if possible).

I already have the code to output the table portion as:

```
mydataframe.to_excel(my_path_name, sheet_name= my_sheet_name, index=False, startrow=7,startcol=0)
```

Is there a way to output the image and text portion directly from Python?

UPDATE:

For clarity, `mydataframe` is exporting the meat and potatoes of the worksheet (data rows and columns). I already have it starting on row 7 of the worksheet in Excel. The header portion is the trouble spot.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what's in `mydataframe`?  Are you actually passing an image object or just the path to the image?

Comment: @ASGM I don't have the image saved into `mydataframe`. I am really just trying to see if it's possible to do rather than having to update it in Excel every time.

Comment: I do have the image imported using `Image.open(file_ref)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and thanks for all of the help.

The simple answer is to use the `xlsxwriter` package as the engine. In other words assume that the image is saved at the path `/image.png`. Then the code to insert the data into the excel file with the image located at the top of the data would be:

```
# Importing packages and storing string for image file
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import numpy as np
image_file = '/image.png'

# Creating a fictitious data set since the actual data doesn't matter
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2),columns=['a','b'])

# Opening the xlsxwriter object to a path on the C:/ drive
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/file.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')

dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Arbitrary', startrow=3)

# Accessing the workbook / worksheet
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Arbitrary']

# Inserting the image into the workbook in cell A1
worksheet.insert_image('A1',image_file)

# Closing the workbook and saving the file to the specified path and filename
writer.save()
```

And now I have an image on the top of my excel file. Huzzah!

Comment: You can then go about exporting the text in into the same sheet in different cells using the `worksheet.write_string()` or the `worksheet.write_rich_string()` functions.